# Difference between markerclusterer.js, markerclusterer_compiled.js and markerclusterer_packed.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, markerclusterer

I see this a lot in jquery plug-ins. what I know is that  markerclusterer.js is human readable code but the difference between the two second files is not quite clear. can anyone explain to me the difference please.And in which case we use every type of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not to sure about _compiled.js but I think that _packed.js reduces all the code to one line, and eliminstes all useless things such as comments, spaces, it makes it VERY hard to understand the code, but the file size will be smaller, therefore the computer will read it quicker, I'm not 100% certain though.